# can't load package: github.com/dmgk/faker expects import "syreclabs.com/go/faker"

Tags: go, faker

I'm using the [`github.com/dmgk/faker`](https://github.com/dmgk/faker) Go package to generate fake names. But, whenever I try to import the package, I get this error message:

> can't load package: package github.com/dmgk/faker: code in directory
>   /home/nakama/go_projects/src/github.com/dmgk/faker expects import
>   "syreclabs.com/go/faker"

I've read the `dmkg/faker` page and follow the instruction there by running this: `go get -u syreclabs.com/go/faker`. I get no error.

But when I try to `go get -v` in my program (which imports `dmgk/faker`) it still shows the same error. I also have tried to `go build` in `dmkg/faker`, it still generate the same error.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try to use `import "syreclabs.com/go/faker"` instead of `import "github.com/dmgk/faker"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go allows packages to [declare that they must be imported using a specific name](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking), and this package [includes that declaration](https://github.com/dmgk/faker/blob/master/faker.go).  In your own application code, if you `import "github.com/dmgk/faker"`, it will fail with the quoted error, and you need to change it to the other path.

Comment: cool, so what I need to do is `import "syreclabs.com/go/faker"` instead right?

Comment: Also you must to run go get -u syreclabs.com/go/faker